# Order of commands with thread dispatch

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Our instructor presented us this code in class.
 
He claims that for the given random thread ids
 (e.g. main thread 9443200 'hello' thread 9454310 and 'world' thread 9454388)
 It is possible that the output 
"1. world - 9454388"
will be printed before the **first** time the output
"thread id: 9443200"
is printed
In my opinion it is not possible, because the main thread is the one dispatching the 'world' thread, but it is also the one dispatching the hello thread, where it(the main thread) prints the
 "thread id: 9443200" message, thus in no context-switch scenario it is possible to have the order of prints he mentioned.

```
template<class Function>
class Runner {
    Function func;
    std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> m = std::make_unique<std::mutex>();
public:
    Runner(Function f): func(f) {}
// runInNewThread creates a new thread and calls func in a loop
    template<typename... Params>
    std::thread runInNewThread(int times, Params&&... params) {
        std::thread t(
        [times, &params..., this]() {
            auto t_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
            for(int i=1; i<=times; ++i) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*m);
                func(i, std::forward<Params>(params)...);
                cout << " - " << t_id << endl;
            }
            cout << t_id << " finished the loop!" << endl;
        });
        cout << "thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << endl;
        return t;
    }
};

template<class Function>
Runner<Function> createRunner(Function f) {
    return f;
}

int main() {
    auto runner = createRunner (
    [](int i, auto obj) {
        cout << i << ". " << obj;
    }
                  );
    auto t1 = runner.runInNewThread(3, "hello");
    auto t2 = runner.runInNewThread(3, "world");
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Am i missing something in the way of context-switching and threads in cpp?
Thanks!

Comment: Agree. I can see "1. hello - 9454310" "thread id: 9443200", but not "world" getting in there first. Recommend asking the instructor for clarification